# Unable to run commands against Selenium standlone server running as background process

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running Ubuntu 10, Java 1.6, and Selenium stand-alone remote control server 2.0b3.  I want to run my Selenium server as a background process.  I have this in a system startup script …

```
su selenium -c 'java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar -userExtensions /opt/selenium/user-extensions.js &>/dev/null &'
```

where "selenium" is a user on my Linux system.  I've noticed that unless I'm logged in as the user "selenium", even when the process runs, my commands always die with the error, "ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?"

How can I run the selenium server without having to be logged in to the system? - Dave

Comment: Which `sessionId` is Selenium complaining about? If it means the `setsid(2)` / `getsid(2)` session, try using the `start-stop-daemon(8)` init-script helper tool instead of `su`. Does it mean something Selenium-specific instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the startup application dialog box, enter this and save. When you 
machine restarts, this will be executed. Run your selenium tests and 
see if its working

```
java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar - userExtensions /opt/selenium/user-extensions.js
```